# go array initialization containing a string literal

Tags: string, go, append, slice

I'm trying to initialize a byte array as a mix of numbers and a string.  I've managed to do it using a pair of appends, or by splitting the string into individual chars, but for the sake of readability is there a way to do it as a single initializer containing a string?

```
// method 1, with two appends
a := []byte{1, 2}
a = append(a, []byte("foo")...);
a = append(a, 3, 4);

// method 2, splitting the string into chars
b := []byte{1, 2, 'f', 'o', 'o', 3, 4)
```

Comment: It is correct but you should use a pair of {} instead of { and ).

Answer (score 3):

What you did in your first attempt in 3 lines is probably more readable that any one-liners:

(You can try all the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/V5OHiXmisoc).)

```
// Doing one-by-one:
a := []byte{1, 2}
a = append(a, []byte("foo")...)
a = append(a, 3, 4)
fmt.Println(a)

// Using individual chars:
a = []byte{1, 2, 'f', 'o', 'o', 3, 4}
fmt.Println(a)

// Using a single string literal:
a = []byte("\x01\x02foo\x03\x04")
fmt.Println(a)

// Using several "nested" appends:
a = append(append([]byte{1, 2}, []byte("foo")...), 3, 4)
fmt.Println(a)
```

Except if you create a helper function:

```
func concat(s ...[]byte) []byte {
    var res []byte
    for _, v := range s {
        res = append(res, v...)
    }
    return res
}
```

And then using it:

```
// With a utility function:
a = concat([]byte{1, 2}, []byte("foo"), []byte{3, 4})
fmt.Println(a)

// With a utility function, formatted differently:
a = concat(
    []byte{1, 2},
    []byte("foo"),
    []byte{3, 4},
)
fmt.Println(a)
```

You could also do it using a single keyed composite literal and a single `copy()` call to "insert" the string:

```
// With keyed literal and copy:
a = []byte{1, 2, 5: 3, 4}
copy(a[2:], "foo")
fmt.Println(a)
```

Still I don't think it's more readable or worth it.

---

### Concat optimization

As per comments left below, @EliasVanOotegem benchmarked the solution above (using append on an empty slice) and compared it to summing the total capacity of the byte slice required and allocating that memory in one go. The latter turns out to be slightly more efficiend (~20%), so I'll include that version below:

```
func concat(s ...[]byte) []byte {
    c := 0
    for _, v := range s {
        c += len(v)
    }
    res := make([]byte, 0, c) // allocate everything
    for _, v := range s {
        res = append(res, v...)
    }
    return res
}
```

I personally would use the following optimized version which does not require slice header assignments as it uses the builtin `copy()`:

```
func concat(s ...[]byte) []byte {
    size := 0
    for _, v := range s {
        size += len(v)
    }
    res, i := make([]byte, size), 0
    for _, v := range s {
        i += copy(res[i:], v)
    }
    return res
}
```

Comment: Just curious what benchmarking would say about the `concat` func if you specify a cap by first iterating over the `[]byte` arguments and just do something like `size := 0` and a simple `for i := range s { size += len(s[i]) }` and use `res := make([]byte, 0, size)`. It would ensure no over-allocation, and only 1 alloc call is actually made

Comment: OK, really micro-optimisation, but hacked out a little benchmark. `Concat2` is the one with multiple allocations (ie no cap specified):

`BenchmarkConcat-8     20000000         82.5 ns/op`

vs

`BenchmarkConcat2-8    20000000        109 ns/op`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I just wanted to show the option of using a utility function and its basic implementation. If I would need this and would use it a lot, obviously I would optimize it. In that case I would just preallocate the big slice and use `copy()` instead of `append()`, so you can get rid of slice header assignments.

Answer (score 2):

I think I misunderstood what you are trying initially. You could write it as a string with hex embedded:

```
c := []byte("\x01\x02foo\x03\x04")
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW : it is possible to remove the cast to `[]byte(...)` in the append call :

```
a := []byte{65, 66}
a = append(a, "foo"...)
a = append(a, 67, 68)

fmt.Printf("%s", a)

// outputs : ABfooCD
```

[see it on play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/us75l0Adzbp)